# Pass method parameter to an action in googlemock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I use Gmock for a method call, that returns an element of the QList heightsFromCsvResult as out parameter. Here is the currently working code:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*_mockAttributeRepository, getGeometryHeightValues(_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(heightsFromCsvResult.at(0)), Return(true)))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(heightsFromCsvResult.at(1)), Return(true)))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(heightsFromCsvResult.at(2)), Return(true)))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(heightsFromCsvResult.at(3)), Return(true)));
```

The first parameter lineNumber from

```
getGeometryHeightValues(int lineNumber, QPair<QString, QString>)
```

is the index for heightsFromCsvResult.at(lineNumber).

Now I try to use Gmock in a more generic way:

```
int* mockLineNumber = new int;
EXPECT_CALL(*_mockAttributeRepository, getGeometryHeightValues(_,_))
   .Times(4)
   .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(mockLineNumber), SetArgReferee<1>(heightsFromCsvResult.at(*(mockLineNumber))), Return(true)));
```

But this code does not work, because mockLineNumber is never written by Gmock. But the EXPECT_CALL is satisfied.

Does anyone see the problem in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a variable set with **SaveArg** within the same **EXPECT_CALL** does not seem to be working, what you could do instead is to go through a **custom action** that sets the second argument using argument 0 as index on the passed container.

```
ACTION_P(SetArg1WithValueFromPassedArgumentUsingArg0AsIndex, param)
{
  arg1 = param.at(arg0);
} 

int* mockLineNumber = new int;
EXPECT_CALL(*_mockAttributeRepository, getGeometryHeightValues(_,_))
   .Times(4)
   .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(mockLineNumber), SetArg1WithValueFromPassedArgumentUsingArg0AsIndex(heightsFromCsvResult), Return(true)));
```

Unless you need **mockLineNumber** for something else you could remove that part.